# Django Deprecation Warning or ImproperlyConfigured error - Passing a 3-tuple to django.conf.urls.include() is not supported

Tags: python, django

I have a deprecation warning in Django 1.11:

```
RemovedInDjango20Warning: Passing a 3-tuple to django.conf.urls.include() is deprecated. Pass a 2-tuple containing the list of patterns and app_name, and provide the namespace argument to include() instead.
  url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls))
```

In Django 2.0 this gives the error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Passing a 3-tuple to include() is not supported. 
Pass a 2-tuple containing the list of patterns and app_name, and provide the namespace argument to include() instead.
```

How should I change `url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls))`? I tried to look at the documentation, but I have no clue ...

Here is my urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^admin/django-ses/', include('django_ses.urls')),
    url(r'^api/1.0/', include('feedcrunch_api_v1.urls')),
    url(r'^oauth/', include('oauth.urls')),
    url(r'^@(?P<feedname>\w+)/admin/', include('feedcrunch_rssadmin.urls')),
    url(r'^@(?P<feedname>\w+)/', include('feedcrunch_rssviewer.urls')),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    url(r'', include('feedcrunch_home.urls')),
]
```

Comment: As an aside, you can remove `admin.autodiscover()` -- it has not been required [since Django 1.7](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/releases/1.7/#app-loading-refactor).

Answer (score 148, accepted):

As of Django 1.9, [the old way of including the admin urls is deprecated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/releases/1.9/#passing-a-3-tuple-or-an-app-name-to-include). You should pass `admin.site.urls` directly to `url()`, without the call to `include()`:

```
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    ...
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this on my Macbook. I had a virtual environment activated with Django 2.0 installed. But `django-admin` was still pointing to a system level install from an old version of django. My solution was to uninstall the system level django. After that, `django-admin` was pointing to the newer virtualenv version.

Answer (score 0):

It's problem belongs to your global virtualenv.First step deactivate your virtualenv and delete your old django module.

1.Deactivate your virtualenv `deactivate`

2.Delete your old django module `pip uninstall django`

3.Activate yor virtualenv and install new django module

Happy Coding