# Django urlpatterns issue

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I am working from the Python Crash Course from no starch by Eric Matthes. The book is working with Python 2.0 and I am trying to essentially convert it to work with Python 3.0. I am having an issue with include(). The error I am receiving in command prompt is:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: passing a 3-tuple to
> include() is not supported. Pass a 2-tuple containing the list of
> patterns and app_name, and provide the namespace argument to include()
> instead.

Here is my code:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'', include('learning_logs.urls', namespace='learning_logs')),
]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django Deprecation Warning or ImproperlyConfigured error - Passing a 3-tuple to django.conf.urls.include() is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43324005/django-deprecation-warning-or-improperlyconfigured-error-passing-a-3-tuple-to)

Comment: No the issue is not with the include on admin. The issue is with the include('learning_logs.urls', namespace='learning_logs')

Comment: I'm the author of PCC. You are working from an old version of the first edition of the book; later printings of the first edition moved away from the `url()` function and used the newer `path()` function. There are numerous other changes that will be hard to sort through as well. I strongly suggest you work from the second edition of the book for this project, or find a different Django-specific resource to learn from.

Comment: Thank you. My plan was to still follow the chapter's but build the code from the django documentation rather than the book examples, but I will check out the second edition.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should always mention your Django version when you are asking questions.
As per your code, this is the old way of doing things. If I'm not wrong, starting from Django 2 you have to do this in a little different way.

There are 2 ways to solve it.

First way:
change your code to this:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
    learning_logs_patterns = ([
         url(...),
    ], 'learning_logs')  
    
    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
        url(r'^polls/', include(learning_logs_patterns, namespace='learning_logs')),
    ]
```

Second way:

in mysite.urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'', include('learning_logs.urls')),
]
```

in learning_logs.urls.py

```
app_name = 'polls'  
urlpatterns = [...]
```

For Details see the documentation : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/releases/1.9/#passing-a-3-tuple-or-an-app-name-to-include

A little suggestion: Starting from Django 2 there is a better way for declaring urls.It's called path(). See documentation for details: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urls/

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response. I am using Django 3.1. I'm guessing this means that the book I am working from is using an older version. I will try to implement your changes.

Comment: what does [...] mean? Are you saying to literally type this in or is this a filler? currently my code in learning_log.urls is:

    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    ]

Comment: That's a filler.

Comment: I have not been able to get either to work. The first option generates a new error. url() missing 1 required positional argument: 'view'. I think this may be because of what I'm typing int he learning_logs_patterns (..). I currently have it typed like this. learning_logs_patterns = ([
    url('learning_logs.urls'),
    ], 'learning_logs')